# Query error in Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to select a single row from the database with a query 
but the problem seems to be in this line of code:

```
access.execquery("SELECT Customer_Table.* FROM Customer_Table WHERE (Customer_ID LIKE @CustomerID )")
```

The entire subroutine is as follows:

```
Private Sub selectuser(CustomerID As String)
    'Query User
    access.addparam("@CustomerID", CustomerID)
    access.execquery("SELECT Customer_Table.* FROM Customer_Table WHERE (Customer_ID LIKE @CustomerID )")

    'Report and Errors or no record found
    If NotEmpty(access.exception) OrElse access.Recordcount < 1 Then MsgBox(access.exception) : Exit Sub

    'Get First From Found
    Dim r As DataRow = access.DBDT.Rows(0)

    'Populate textboxs with data
    TextBox2.Text = r("Customer_ID").ToString
    TextBox3.Text = r("Company_Name").ToString

    'Enable Delete Button
    NewCustomerToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Whenever I execute the program it terminates with empty error message.

Comment: Try to see what the character variable `@CustomerID` contains before this query.

Comment: it contains numbers or text (string in general), however i tried before to convert them by .tostring, the same error !! @artur

Comment: Display the value of Recordcount, what it is? I'm guessing it might be -1.

Comment: Public Sub execquery(query As String)
        'reset quesry statistics 
        Recordcount = 0
        exception = ""

        Try
            'Excute command and fill Database
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDa = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBcmd)
            Recordcount = DBDa.Fill(DBDT)

        Catch ex As Exception
            exception = ex.Message
        End Try

    End Sub 
@atur

Comment: is there a way that i can select a row from the database easier than what i am trying to do ?

Comment: when i removed the access.Recordcount < 1   the error jumped to the next line Dim r As DataRow = access.DBDT.Rows(1)

Comment: If the `access` object is some sort of "helper" get rid of it or at least show it.  Queries are so single purpose that there is very little that is reusable on them.  There is also no reason to query the DB at all if you have a DataTable build from `Customer_Table` you can filter or select from it to find whatever.